# C# graph drawing library?

Tags: c#, graphics, graph-theory

I'm looking for a (free) library which allows me to draw a [CFG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) (control flow graph). Something like [yFiles](http://yworks.com/), but free or preferably open source? Ideally this library would allow the user to navigate the graph (and modify it), i.e. the graph isn't just a static a priori rendered bitmap.
Ideas?

**Update:**
[Glee](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx) in combination with the mentioned QuickGraph library seems to work pretty nice. thx

**Update2:**
[Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) seems to be the most powerful library currently. There is also a nice [tutorial](http://sachabarber.net/?p=815) on how to use it.

Comment: GLEE is now called [Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/msagl/) (MSAGL). MSAGL is distributed in a binary form only. A commercial license has to be bought.

Comment: I'm not sure about the solution, but maybe this could be useful also: https://github.com/komorra/NodeEditorWinforms

Comment: The best commercial solution, in my point of view, is [yfiles.net](https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles-net), see [demos](https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles/demos). This is a good reference on how far this technology can go.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You might want to check out [QuickGraph](http://www.codeplex.com/quickgraph).

[NodeXL](http://www.codeplex.com/NodeXL) might also be of interest (visualization library). It's WPF, but you can use a container to host it if you need WinForms.

Comment: Looks interesting, though this seems to be the "algorithm part", not the "visualization part", right?

Comment: Just added some info on NodeXL, which is a visualization API.

Comment: NodeXL is a template for Excel, is it really suitable for c#?

Answer (score 11):

Try out this (Efficient Sugiyama algorithm is your friend):

[Graph#](http://codeplex.com/graphsharp)

Answer (score 5):

https://graphx.codeplex.com/

Inspired by Graph#, actively developed and much more extensible.

Comment: It's free and open-source https://github.com/panthernet/GraphX

Answer (score 3):

I use [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to generate this sort of graph. My app generates the **.dot** file that can then is then passed into GraphViz. It supports a load of file formats, such as bmp, jpg, png, pdf, svg etc etc.