# Clear all Bitmap drawings using push button

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-forms-designer

I made several drawings using Windows forms application visual studio Bitmap, my goal is to clear all drawings when I press the push button (make the background clear)
 The Following code is not exactly what my original code but this is how I created each drawing

```
Rectangle area;
Bitmap creature;//this only one drawing but I have several
Graphics scG;
Bitmap background;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  background = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
  area = new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 50);
  creature = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Image.png");
}

public Bitmap Draw()
{
  Graphics scG = Graphics.FromImage(background);
  scG.DrawImage(creature, area);

        return background;
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // I want to clear all the drawings by push this button
}
```

Comment: Since you are drawing into a Bitmap you created from scratch you just fill that Bitmap with a Color, like white or transparent: graphics.Clear(yourColor) or re-create it from scratch. You can't take back a single drawing, though. You need to cache the previous step if you need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is duplicate , see this link : 
[How to delete a drawn circle in c# windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124638/how-to-delete-a-drawn-circle-in-c-sharp-windows-form)

or test these Code :

```
Graphics.Clear();
```

or

```
Control.Invalidate();
```

or

```
this.Invalidate();
```

Comment: no one of these does work with my code I got an error:   there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'color' of 'Graphic.Clear (Color)'

Comment: @MohanadAlNuaimi use two button , first for drow and secont for clean , remove anything in form load and paste in first and in the second button white this.Invalidate();

Comment: I found a way to solve the problem, Thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove things drawn on a bitmap.

Why don't just dump the old `background` bitmap and create a new one?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Dump by `background.Dispose` and then create a new one like you did in `Form1_Load`

Answer (score 0):

The real way is to use event Paint:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(creature, area); // draw your image here...
}
```

To delete, just do nothing in Form1_Paint, and call Refresh();

Comment: No, it is perfectly fine to draw into a Bitmap.