# Data flow or flow diagrams visualization libraries

Tags: java, .net, graphics, data-visualization, dataflow-diagram

I have an application where I have a collection of objects where each one is representing something and each define how they are connected to other objects in the collection by specifying the destination object id and the port that that object to connect to.

These objects together represent a dataflow and I am looking for any library out there that to use to create a visualization diagram from my objects and their relationships. If you are familiar with matlab and simulink, this is very similar to what matlab simulink does to any given simulink object and draw a diagram like below which is the visualization of the data flow of the simulink objects diagram.

[image]

There are many graphing libraries out there but I am wondering if anybody could point me to any library that is **specifically geared around dataflow visualization** ?

Comment: Related answers but not quick what I am after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737771/c-sharp-graph-drawing-library

Comment: This is not free but the Hierarchical Layout is what I am looking for. Hierarchical Layout yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_practicalinfo_gallery.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853093/drawing-directed-acyclic-graphs-minimizing-edge-crossing